# How to trigger action on end-of-statement?

Tags: c++, stream

Suppose that I want to create a stream that would perform an action at the end of the statement, so that

```
myStream << "Hello, " << "World!";
```

would print "Hello, World!\n" **in one shot**. Not "Hello, \nWorld!\n" and not "Hello, World!", but "Hello, World\n", as if `;` would trigger appending `\n` and flushing the buffers.

The rationale for that is a stream class that writes to both `stdout` and a logfile, with the logfile entries having certain prefixes and suffixes.

For example, if my target was HTML I would want this code:

```
myStream << "Hello, " << "World!";
myStream << "Good bye, " << "cruel World!";
```

to print like this:

```
<p>Hello, World!</p>
<p>Good bye, cruel World!</p>
```

and **not** like this:

```
<p>Hello, </p><p>World!</p>
<p>Good bye, </p><p>cruel World!</p>
```

Now, if I implement `LogStream` sort of like this:

```
LogStream & LogStream::operator<<( const std::string & text );
```

I won't be able to distinguish between `<<` in the middle of the statements from the ones in the beginning/ending of the statements.

If I implement `LogStream` sort of like this:

```
LogStream LogStream::operator<<( const std::string & text );
```

and try to massage the input in the destructor I would get multiple destructors at once at the end of the block.

Finally, I can implement this my requiring `endl` at the end of each statement, but I'd rather not bother the caller with the necessity to do so.

Thus the question: how one implements such a stream in a caller-transparent fashion?

Comment: You can't know when the calling chain ends, so nah, you can't achieve that.

Comment: Make your stream's `operator <<` return a temporary object with a pointer to the stream. This object has member `operator <<` that redirects all requests to the original stream, and its destructor makes an additional entry to the stream.

Comment: `I'd rather not bother the caller with the necessity to do so.` And what about situations when the caller *doesn't* want a \n immediately? Don't force such things.

Comment: The Law of Least Surprise suggests pursuing this course would end in maintenance problems. The screams of frustration from those expecting normal stream behaviour would be music in the ears of gremlins around the world.

Comment: Ok, ok, I've got it, you don't like the idea. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented something like this once for a custom logging system.  I created a class that buffered input and then its destructor flushed the buffer to my log file.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class LogStream
{
private:
    std::stringstream m_ss;

    void flush()
    {
        const std::string &s = m_ss.str();
        if (s.length() > 0)
        {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
            logfile << "<p>" << s << "</p>" << std::endl;
        }
    }    

public:
    LogStream() {}

    ~LogStream()
    {
        flush();
    }

    template <typename T>
    LogStream& operator<<(const T &t)
    {
        m_ss << t;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    LogStream& operator<<( std::ostream& (*fp)(std::ostream&) )
    {
        // TODO: if fp is std::endl, write to log and reset m_ss
        fp(m_ss);
        return *this;
    }

    void WriteToLogAndReset()
    {
        flush();
        m_ss.str(std::string());
        m_ss.clear();
    }
};
```

For single statements that flush on the final `;`, each message would use a new instance of the class:

```
LogStream() << "Hello, " << "World!";
LogStream() << "Good bye, " << "cruel World!";
```

To allow multiple statements to write to a single message, create the object and do not let it go out of scope until the last statement is done:

```
{
LogStream myStream;
myStream << "Hello, ";
myStream << "World!";
}

{
LogStream myStream;
myStream << "Good bye, ";
myStream << "cruel World!";
}
```

To reuse an existing instance for multiple messages, tell it to flush and reset in between each message:

```
{
LogStream myStream;
myStream << "Hello, " << "World!";
myStream.WriteToLogAndReset();
myStream << "Good bye, " << "cruel World!";
}
```

I like this approach because it gives the caller more flexibility in deciding when each message is ready to be written to the log file.  For instance, I use this to send multiple values to a single log message where those values are obtained from decision-making code branches.  This way, I can stream some values, make some decisions, stream some more values, etc and then send the completed message to the log.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
myStream << "Hello, " << "World!";
```

Is actually multiple statements. It's equivalent to:

```
ostream& result = myStream << "Hello, ";
result << "World!";
```

There *are* some tricks to do what you want by returning an unnamed temporary object (which are destroyed at the end of the full-expression). [Here is some example code](https://ideone.com/D9pCEj).

Answer (score 0):

I have a little code that I haven't gotten round to doing anything constructive with that I think is doing what you're asking.

It works by using a *proxy class* (`log_buffer`) to build up the string in a `std::stringstream` object. At the end of the expression the `log_buffer` *proxy* object calls the main `log_writer`
 object to process the whole line contained in the `std::stringstream`.

```
class log_writer
{
    // ultimate destination
    std::ostream* sink = nullptr;

    // proxy class to do the << << << chaining
    struct log_buffer
    {
        log_writer* lw;
        std::stringstream ss;

        void swap(log_buffer& lb)
        {
            if(&lb !=this)
            {
                std::swap(lw, lb.lw);
                std::swap(ss, lb.ss);
            }
        }

        log_buffer(log_writer& lw): lw(&lw) {}
        log_buffer(log_buffer&& lb): lw(lb.lw), ss(std::move(lb.ss)) { lb.lw = nullptr; }
        log_buffer(log_buffer const&) = delete;

        log_buffer& operator=(log_buffer&& lb)
        {
            swap(lb);
            return *this;
        }

        log_buffer& operator=(log_buffer const&) = delete;

        // update the log_writer after the last call to << << <<
        ~log_buffer() { if(lw) lw->add_line(ss); }

        template<typename DataType>
        log_buffer operator<<(DataType const& t)
        {
            ss << t;
            return std::move(*this);
        }
    };

    void swap(log_writer& lw)
    {
        if(&lw != this)
        {
            std::swap(sink, lw.sink);
        }
    }

public:
    log_writer(std::ostream& sink): sink(&sink) {}
    log_writer(log_writer&& lw): sink(lw.sink) { lw.sink = nullptr; }
    log_writer(log_writer const&) = delete;

    log_writer& operator=(log_writer&& lw)
    {
        swap(lw);
        return *this;
    }

    log_writer& operator=(log_writer const&) = delete;

    // output the final line
    void add_line(std::stringstream& ss)
    {
        // Do any special line formatting here
        if(sink) (*sink) << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename DataType>
    struct log_buffer operator<<(DataType const& data)
    {
        return std::move(log_buffer(*this) << data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("test.log");
    log_writer lw1(ofs);
    log_writer lw2(std::cout);

    lw1 << "lw1 " << 2.93 << " A";
    lw2 << "lw2 " << 3.14 << " B";

    std::swap(lw1, lw2);

    lw1 << "lw1 " << 2.93 << " C";
    lw2 << "lw2 " << 3.14 << " D";
}
```